# Best seller extension of magento does not show any product on home page....?

Tags: magento

I have installed best seller extension in magento. And call there shortcode in home page.
But not any single product shown on this page .

Answer (score 0):

Best seller products will be shown only after you place the order & order status is complete. 
Have placed any order for your store.

Comment: yes, i have placed three orders , but it has not shown in home page. when i installed it in localhost , then it works , but when i installed it on live site , then it not shown any product even after placed the order.  And there is also not any java script confliction in console pannel.